# VIM disabling replace mode

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

In VIM, 
I find myself reflexively hitting the insert key, before entering text. 
Normally because I have been doing some reading and often, but not always,
I'll have switched out to do a search or something. (into normal mode).
When I am already in insert mode,  hitting the insert key put me into replace mode.

For my personal workstyle, and the kind of work I am doing,
I almost never want to be in replace mode.

Ideally I would like the behavour of the insert key to be:

```
Insert: If in insert mode, do nothing,
If not in insert mode, change to insert mode.
```

I would like to make the behavour of

```
Shift+Insert: Change to Replace Mode
(I don't use shift insert for pasting -  i've got tused to using P for that
```

How can I do this?
I've sure it can be done with one of the many many remap commands, in my .vimrc.

Comment: Force yourself to abandon your bad habits instead of looking for ways to mitigate their effects.

Comment: @romainl: Why? (I honestly want a explaination, you might be onto something.)

Comment: When you have a disease that causes large green star-shaped stains to appear on your limbs, the solution is not to cover them with clothes or make-up: the solution is to treat the disease. Your bad habit is causing unwanted effects, the solution is not to hide those effects: it's to fight your bad habits.

Comment: I think romainl is trying to say there are MUCH better ways to enter insert mode than pressing the "insert" key. The usual way to enter insert mode would be using `i` or `a` to enter insert mode at the cursor; `I` or `A` to enter insert mode at the beginning/end of the line; `o` or `O` to start insert mode on a new line; `cc` or `S` to clear the current line and start inserting there; etc. There is also the consideration of WHY you don't realize you're already in insert mode. There is a pretty prominent cursor difference, there is a mode indicator near the status line, etc.

Comment: It is also possible to make it REALLY obvious by changing colorscheme, etc. in insert mode. But that's probably overkill.

Comment: romainl: there's an Esperanto disease?

Comment: @Ben I Have issues with some of my terminals that hide the cursor difference and don't show the status line. Fixing that might be a more sensible choice.
The issue I have with using `i` is that if I am already in insert, then I get random `i`s in my source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these:

```
imap <Insert> <Nop>
inoremap <S-Insert> <Insert>
```